# Проблема с анализом трафика flash-приложения

Tags: http, flash, tcp, requests, flash-player

Есть многопользовательская браузерная флеш-игра drako.ru. Хотел узнать, какие запросы отправляет клиент серверу при определенных действиях(напасть на монстра, выпить бутыль и т.д.). Сколько не анализировал, http-запросы используются только для приема/отправки второстепенной информации(получение картинок,ссылки и т.д.). Думал, возможно, клиент с сервером обмениваются информацией с помощью сокетов, но и тут анализ ничего не дал. Где-то прочитал, что, наверняка, общаются "напрямую" через TCP. Что можете подсказать, начать ли узнавать какой открывается порт для общения и начинать напрямую через wireshark смотреть, что приходит и уходит?

Comment: Да, используйте Wireshark. Только скорее всего там увидите HTTPS траффик.

Comment: `общаются "напрямую" через TCP` - что за ерунда? общаться можно только через сокеты.

Comment: Имел ввиду, отправку TCP-пакетов на сервер, простите мое невежество. Но спец. плагины для анализа сокетов молчали, в чем может быть дело?